# How to delay audio after a specific position with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a 10 seconds `a.mp4` with two streams: `Stream #0` is a video stream and `Stream #1` is a audio stream.

Now, I want to delay the audio stream by 4 seconds after the time position 00:03. It is to say, in the output file, I want that: 00:00-00:03 is the original audio, 00:03-00:07 has no sound, 00:07-00:14 is the original 00:03-00:10 audio.

I've tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -t 00:00:03 -i a.map4 -itsoffset 4 -ss 00:00:03 -i a.mp4 -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -codec copy output.mp4
```

But it seems that there are two audio streams in the `output.mp4` and only one of them can be played once. Then I tried `amix` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -t 00:00:03 -i a.mp4 -itsoffset 4 -ss 00:00:03 -i a.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a] amix=inputs=2" -map 0:v output.mp4
```

But it also doesn't work. I'm new to `ffmpeg` so I have no idea what should I do now? Any idea for me? Very much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the asetpts filter to change timestamps, and aresample to (optionally) insert silence in that gap.

`ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -af "asetpts='if(lt(T\,3),PTS,PTS+4/TB)',aresample=async=1" -c:v copy output.mp4`

Test without aresample to see if your player is tolerant of large gaps in the audio stream.